# Closing bootstrap modal through console

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am using java servlets and jsp to create a website and one of my requirements is that if any anonymous user tries to visit any page that needs authentication/login a modal should appear above the page and the modal cannot close until you login or sign up (As in case of quora). So i am checking whether the user is logged in by checking the session attribute in every jsp and if the session attribute is not present i am showing the login modal with backdrop= static using java script.

I have a query, what if someone hides the login modal through console using 
$("#id").modal("hide") (As i am using bootstrap modal). Is there anyway i can handle this or do i have to take care of this at the backend?

Answer (score 1):

You should take care of it at the **back-end** as after all the user can disable javascript, instead do it this way:

```
if(loggedIn)
    //show content for authenticated users

else
    // display the login form
```

---

**Update:**

As in this [**PHP Fiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/hqye-f40z) - *hit RUN to show the result* - it is the same above idea but in PHP, if you alter the value of `$loggedIn` to `true` it will show the content which needs authentication, if `$loggedIn` is `false` it will show a login form

Comment: So this cannot be taken care at the front end? Aint there any property through which a bootstrap modal cannot be closed even through console?

Comment: It can, but it could be by-passed with disabling javascript, this is why it is a must to validate users inputs on server-side  even though some of them can be validated on client side, because it could be altered on the client side

Comment: Thankyou @Mi-Creativity

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could assign an event handler to the hide event.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

```
$('#id').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // if some condition, dont let them hide it
})
```

but if a user can get into things they aren't meant to by invoking this js, they could also just inspect the dom and delete this html element.

Having code like this could help keep people honest but if its a security issue I would make sure to handle it on the server as well.

Comment: Hi Chris, i am handling the  code at the backend as well by not getting any data if  i am not able to get the session attribute...and redirecting the user to the page and then showing the user the login modal. But is this enough?

Comment: as long as you aren't sending any privileged information to the client for unauthorized users, as @Mi-Creativity mentioned, I would think it's enough. I really don't think you would even need to add logic for the user manually hiding the modal, to be honest. If the user manually hides the modal, there should be no privileged content behind it and they just wouldn't be able to see anything. they would have to navigate somewhere else or refresh the page and then your server code would see they aren't authenticated and present them with the login again.

Comment: Thankyou @Chris .. I will do exactly as mentioned.